# JQuery Mousewheel: How to disable?

Tags: jquery, mousewheel

I am using jquery.mousewheel.js as a part of the jQuery jScrollPane plugin.

I want to disable the mousewheel at some point.

Could someone please recommend a jQuery statement that can do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$("#menu").bind("mousewheel", function() {
    return false;
});
```

Comment: To undo the effect of the code above, run: `$("#menu").unbind("mousewheel");`

Answer (score 5):

Try using `.unmousewheel()`, it should also work.

Comment: for me it did not

Answer (score 0):

the container you must unbind is `jspPane`

In my case i needed to disable it only in the boxes inside `#myOuterContainer`

```
$('#myOuterContainer .jspPane').bind('mousewheel',function(){ return false; });
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are not using the jQuery mousewheel plugin, this worked for me:

```
$("#inputID").bind("wheel", function() {
    return false;
});
```

The only difference is that the `.bind` method takes an argument of `wheel` instead of `mousewheel`

Note: The element I applied this to was on an `input` of type `number`