# Only scroll with the scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a possibility that you only can scroll with the scrollbar in a div and not with the scrollwheel on your mouse?

I prefer that on an one page website.

Comment: What difference does it make?

Comment: You really shouldn't try and modify the default behaviour of the browser, unless you're going for a really high bounce rate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
function stop() {
    return false;
}

document.onmousewheel = stop;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do a bind on mousewheel scroll and disable it.

```
$("#menu").bind("mousewheel", function() {
    return false;
});
```

I'd suggest trying to google your question first, as the answer was pretty easy to find, in fact there's another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702116/jquery-mousewheel-how-to-disable)