# Using mousewheel.js, How to disable 'mousewheel' event temporarily?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel

I'm using the mousewheel.js jquery plugin
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel

How can I disable the 'mousewheel' event temporarily?

Or how can I unbind it and bind it after some time?

```
$(window).on('mousewheel', function(event) {

});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702116/jquery-mousewheel-how-to-disable

Comment: `$(window).off('mousewheel')` ? [disconnecting events in jquery](https://learn.jquery.com/events/handling-events/#disconnecting-events)

Comment: Here's the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/bfdyxobn/11/
I might be doing something stupid, but after using .off() on click event, it still triggers 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To bind:

```
$(window).bind("mousewheel", function(e){ return false;});
```

To unbind:

```
$(window).unbind("mousewheel", function(e){ return false;});
```